# How do you parse a web page and extract all the href links?

Tags: html, parsing, groovy

I want to parse a web page in Groovy and extract all of the href links and the associated text with it.

If the page contained these links:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a><br />
<a href="http://www.apple.com">Apple</a>
```

the output would be:

```
Google, http://www.google.com<br />
Apple, http://www.apple.com
```

I'm looking for a Groovy answer.  AKA. The easy way!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming well-formed XHTML, slurp the xml, collect up all the tags, find the 'a' tags, and print out the href and text.

```
input = """<html><body>
<a href = "http://www.hjsoft.com/">John</a>
<a href = "http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
<a href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a>
</body></html>"""

doc = new XmlSlurper().parseText(input)
doc.depthFirst().collect { it }.findAll { it.name() == "a" }.each {
    println "${it.text()}, ${it.@href.text()}"
}
```

Comment: This approach will not work very well for one simple but true reason - usually website don't have well formed XML. It will work in some cases but not all.

Comment: Here is a good link: http://blog.stannard.net.au/2010/05/12/parsing-html-with-groovy-and-htmlcleaner/

Answer (score 4):

A quick google search turned up a nice looking possibility, [TagSoup](http://blog.foosion.org/2008/06/09/parse-html-the-groovy-way/).

Comment: This site provides a complete example with TagSoup that works.

http://www.cyblex.at/blog/?p=83

I had to change some of the quote marks (' and ") to get it to run but this example is excellent.  The author downloads all the *.mp4 files.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know java but I think that xpath is far better than classic regular expressions in order to get one (or more) html elements.

It is also easier to write and to read.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <a href="1.html">1</a>
      <a href="2.html">2</a>
      <a href="3.html">3</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

With the html above, this expression "/html/body/a" will list all href elements.

Here's a good step by step tutorial http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

Use XMLSlurper to parse the HTML as an XML document and then use the find method with an appropriate closure to select the a tags and then use the list method on GPathResult to get a list of the tags. You should then be able to extract the text as children of the GPathResult.

Answer (score 0):

Try a regular expression. Something like this should work:

```
(html =~ /<a.*href='(.*?)'.*>(.*?)<\/a>/).each { url, text -> 
    // do something with url and text
}
```

Take a look at [Groovy - Tutorial 4 - Regular expressions basics](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+4+-+Regular+expressions+basics) and [Anchor Tag Regular Expression Breaking](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottcate/archive/2004/12/13/281955.aspx).

Comment: Regular Expressions also cure cancer.

Comment: ... at the cost of possible demonic possession http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 0):

Parsing using XMlSlurper only works if HTMl is well-formed.

If your HTMl page has non-well-formed tags, then use regex for parsing the page.

Ex: `<a href="www.google.com">`

here, 'a' is not closed and thus not well formed.

```
 new URL(url).eachLine{
   (it =~ /.*<A HREF="(.*?)">/).each{
       // process hrefs
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Html parser + Regular expressions
Any language would do it, though I'd say Perl is the fastest solution.